# Behavior of console.log and html manipulation not expected using node.js, bootstrap, and jquery

Tags: javascript

I am currently encountering a weird issue as I try to use a bootstrap login form, I have tried to debug in the following way

```
<!-- Login container -->
  <div class="container">
     <form class="form-signin" id="login_form" role="form">
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id ="email" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
      <label class="checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="login_submit" type="submit">Sign in</button>
    </form>
  </div> <!-- /container -->

<div class="container" id="test-container">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <span id="test-error"></span>
    <form id="test-input">
    <input type="text" id="test"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

In a separate file called ui.js

```
$(function(){
    var socket = io.connect();

    $('#login_submit').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("login_submit");
        $('#change').append("y");
    });

    $('#test-input').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = $('#test').val();
        console.log(x);
        $('#change').append("x ");
    });
});
```

I the above code, my goal is to extract information from the bootstrap login info via the submit button, however when it doesn't work I tested the following and the found:

```
$('#login_submit').submit(function(e)
```

doesn't work for both console.log and html manipulation

```
$('#test-input').submit(function(e)
```

works for html manipulation and console.log

Suspects:

Is the bootstraps internal js interfering with my js logic

Side Note:

I did a quite a few testing a tried the documentation and google, can't seem to find any answer, if anyone got any advice I would greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form will be submitted, not the button :)

In your provided code you are listening to the submit-button for being submitted. This never happens because only a form can be submitted - as in you second example you need to bind the submithandler to the form as below:

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("login_submit");
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.submit()` can only be attached to `form` objects ([Doc](https://api.jquery.com/submit/))

This is why your second case works, you are binding to the form, and the first case is binding to the button.